# Use of Maptiler to generate osmdroid zip file

Tags: osmdroid, maptiler

Does this product generate osmdroid zip files ? or does it have a way to convert from TMS to the google tile spec so that a zip file of the tiles can be used in osmdroid?

Answer (score 0):

The new MapTiler (http://www.maptiler.com/) can render tiles in both XYZ (by default as you say "Google tile spec") and TMS (via Advanced options in MapTiler during the rendering).

The osmdroid .zip file is just an archive of the XYZ tiles - you can create it from the structure generated by MapTiler.com with the standard ZIP archiving software.

Alternatively, you can render MBTiles format output from the MapTiler.com directly. MBTiles is a format directly supported by osmdroid as well.